# generic constraints on record type

Tags: generics, f#

I have some issue understandign generic constraints with the following code.
View is a base class within the Xamarin framework (but that is not really important)

```
type GridCoordinates = (View * int * int * int * int)
type GridRecord = { children: GridCoordinates list}
```

given this code I get a compile error here

```
let x = { children = [(new BoxView( Color = Color.Green ), 0, 3, 0, 1)] }
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
                       Expression expected to have type View
```

Now a BoxView is of type View - hmm. So I thought I'd add a little bit of generic constraints into it

```
type GridCoordinates<'T when 'T :> View> = ('T * int * int * int * int)
type GridRecord = { children: GridCoordinates<View> list}
```

But still this gives me the same error. So I added a constrait to GridRecord as well

```
type GridCoordinates<'T when 'T :> View> = ('T * int * int * int * int)
type GridRecord<'T when 'T :> View> = { children: GridCoordinates<'T> list}
```

Now it compiles. I can even remove the constraint from GridCoordinates so that

```
type GridCoordinates<'T> = ('T * int * int * int * int)
type GridRecord<'T when 'T :> View> = { children: GridCoordinates<'T> list}
```

Now all of this is pretty heavy syntax plus somehow the constraint that should be on GridCoordinates invades the definition of GridRecord which is not very nice (imo).

Can somebody please explain to me

a) why does this work as it works and
b) is there a more pleasing solution to this?

Comment: This is becuase F# doesn't do any implicit casting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As John mentioned in the comments, F# does not (in general) implicitly cast class to a base class. So if you create a new instance of `BoxView` and use it in some place where `View` is expected, you need to add an explicit *upcast*:

The following should work with your original definition:

```
let x = { children = [(new BoxView( Color = Color.Green ) :> View, 0, 3, 0, 1)] }
```

The upcast is not needed in a few places (most importantly, when you are using `BoxView` as a parameter of a method that takes `View`). I think F# should be a bit smarter and insert the upcast automatically in this case too...

Comment: Then the question is: why not do that cast that should be possible at all times

Comment: Well, the reason why the compiler does not do it is that it does not know the target type _in general_. It works from left to right and if you write, say, `[ new Dog() ] |> foo`, then it does not know the desired type at the point where the list is created. But I agree that it could be more clever in some specific cases like yours!

Comment: sure in your example `foo` could either require a `Dog list` an `Cat list` or an `Animal list` but where is the problem? If it would be declared as `let foo (v:Dog list) = ...` and I feed it `foo [new Dog(); new Cat()]` then obviously I'd expect an error message that what I feed into `foo` is not a `Dog list`

Comment: My biggest issue here is when interfacing with external (speak c#) libraries that are class based then I ultimately will run into issues like processing a list of super class items - also each of these items is a child class of the super class. The only way to somehow circumvent this is to create a Discriminate Union and to wrap all those child classes into a value constructor. Given the size of that library this simply won't be possible.